# Using d3.js via postgres

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-boot, d3.js

I'm currently studying java spring and d3.js. And found myself on a roadblock since i can't seem to find the right answer to my problem after countless trial and error plus research.

The code below is the one that is my controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import dashboard.atmandcam.model.MyModel;
import dashboard.atmandcam.repo.MyRepo;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepo myRepo;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String sayHi() {
        return "hi";
    }

    @GetMapping("/queries")
    public List<MyModel> getResult(){
        return myRepo.getQueryResult();
    }

    @GetMapping("/queries/{id}")
    public List<MyModel> getSpecific(@PathVariable String id){
        return myRepo.getSpecificResult(id);
    }
}
```

Then this is my d3.js

```
var url = "/queries/31370100";
d3.json(url, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

the result of my controller is w/ the URL (http://localhost:9090/queries/31370100): 
[image: JSON result]

I wanna know how can i use the JSON found on my url in d3.js so i can build my charts around my database.

Comment: The data (`data`) is there, I can't see what's the problem. Just use it to create your dataviz.

Comment: the problem is it's not outputting any data.

Comment: What do you mean? You just have a `console.log` inside the callback, which is doing what you want. What do you expect?

Comment: I do but it's not outputting any data like expected. When i accessed the console part of the website it's just blank.